# how to align content to menu inside a floating div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I will try to explain my problem the best I can.
Currently I'm designing a one page website and I would really like to `fill` the image (as seen below) in the browser window, in which I've succeeded with some jQuery. The `div` with the image has `float:right`.

But here's the problem; on the left I have a `div` set to `float:left` containing the text for that page. I would really like to align the text with the menu (`width:960px; margin: 0 auto`) but I can't seem to figure out how.

I tried creating a 100% width `div` set to position absolute and creating a new `div` inside that with the content but I don't think `position:absolute` is the answer here.

I hope someone can help me out here. This is a screenshot of the website:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksZw7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

i think you want your website in box pattern then just set width in body

```
body{width:960px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

Comment: hello and thank you for your reply.

my website is already in a box pattern, but I want the image (the one on the right) to stay there, and I want to align the div with the text (the one on the left) with the menu ("Claudia Couwenbergh")

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
.text{
  Box-sizing:border-box;
  position:absolute;
  Max-width:960px;
  padding-right:600px;
  left:50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: hey,this works up until the div reaches the browser window when resizing

picture: [link](http://www.imgur.com/xSDR6sR)

Comment: hey man, I'm sorry for not replying.
It didn't work, I think it might be my fault.

am trying again now